# How to use GeoWebCache png files of disk when network is offline?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have to implement showing GeoWebCache png files on network-offline.
I saved GeoWebCache files which is png of road picutres on my local disk. And I want to show these GWC(GwoWebCache) files on Web Browers when network is off.
Following is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tiled GWC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='file:///C:/Users/HP/Downloads/ol.css' type="text/css">
    <script src='file:///C:/Users/HP/Downloads/proj4.js'></script>
    <script src='file:///C:/Users/HP/Downloads/ol-debug.js'></script>
    <script src='file:///C:/Users/HP/Downloads/gwcsource.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>

        var workspace = 'cnpost';
        var featureType = 'lb_ra_road';
        var resolutions =  [140.0, 70.0, 35.0, 17.5, 8.75, 4.375, 2.1875, 1.09375, 0.546875, 0.2734375, 0.13671875, 0.068359375];
        var viewExtent;
        var MapExtent = [14140780.0, 4311780.0, 14284140.0, 4455140.0];
        viewExtent = MapExtent;
        var origin =  [14140780.0, 4311780.0];
        var dispCenter = [234560, 416854.5];
        var dispProj = "EPSG:5186";
        var vWorldProj = "EPSG:900913";
        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            //code: dispProj,
            code: vWorldProj,
            extent: viewExtent,
            units: 'm'
        });

        var tileSource = new ol.source.GWC(({
                //url: 'file:///storage/sdcard0',
                url: 'file:///C:/gwc',
                gridset: 'VWORLD',
                layer : workspace + '_' + featureType,
                tilegrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
                    resolutions: resolutions,
                    extent: viewExtent,
                    origin: origin,
                    tileSize: [256, 256]
                })
            }));

        var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: featureType,
            extent: viewExtent,
            visible: false,
            baseLayer: false,
            source: tileSource
        });

        var layers = [
            layer
        ];

        var view = new ol.View({
            //center: ol.proj.transform(dispCenter, dispProj, vWorldProj),  
            center: dispCenter,
            //center: ol.proj.transform([126.6, 36.78], 'EPSG:4326', vWorldProj),
            //maxResolution : 140,               
            //minResolution : 0.068359375,                
            //maxZoom : 12,                       
            //minZoom : 2,                        
            projection: projection,               
            resolutions: resolutions,                     
            extent: viewExtent,
            zoom: 2,                           
            resolution: 1.09375                    
            //resolution: 0.2734375
            //rotation: 0,                       
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: layers,
            target: 'map',
            view: view
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above code doesn't work.
If you have any good idea, please let me know.
Thanks for your reading.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I use "ol3-gwc-tiled-rebased". I don't know the author, because I can't find the repo, and the code hasn't information.

It works for me, but I use 'file://c:/temp' as url:

```
var layerPlanea = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: ed50lh.extent,
    title: 'Planejament',
    type: 'overlay',
    visible: false,
    source: new ol.source.GWC({
        url: 'file://c:/temp',
        layer: 'Planejament',
        gridset: 'ED50lh',
        projection: ed50lh,
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            resolutions: resolucions,
            origin: [423000, 4576000],
            extent: ed50lh.extent,
            tileSize: 256
        }),
    })
});
```